# Dynamic v-model using v-for value + string in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my JavaScript I have:

```
data: {
    rooms: [
         {type: 'single'},
         {type: 'double'}
         ...
    ],
    selectedSingle: 0,
    selectedDouble: 0,
    ...
},
computed: {
    capitalize: function(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
}
```

In HTML I have:

```
<li v-for="(room, index) in rooms">
    <input type="number" v-model="'selected' + capitalize(room.type)">
</li>
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to access my models in this way, and the only way I see now is to destroy the `v-for` and make it manually, but it's not the best solution because I have many "rooms". Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are attempting to access a `data` property via string. For that you can use the object access property notation (`obj['propname']`) using `$data` as the object:

```
<input type="number" v-model="$data['selected' + capitalize(room.type)]">
```

Plus your computed should really be a method:

```
  methods: {                                // changed from computed to method
    capitalize: function(string) {
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rooms: [
      {type: 'single'},
      {type: 'double'}
    ],
    selectedSingle: 111,
    selectedDouble: 222,
  },
  methods: {                                // changed from computed to method
    capitalize: function(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(room, index) in rooms">
      <input type="number" v-model="$data['selected' + capitalize(room.type)]">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Exactly what i need. Thanks

Comment: Great! Here are [**the `vm.$data` api docs**](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data) for future reference.

Comment: @acdcjunior I had the same issue and this helped me! But if I'm honest, I'm not really sure what's going on here. Why is it necessary to use `$data`? Why doesn't `room.type` work?

Comment: @eysikal `$data` represents the whole `data: {` object. This is the only "vue-specific" thing here. Other than that, it's just regular JavaScript property accessing via brackets notation

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now. It looks like `v-model=""` is expecting a raw string, not a variable. So using `v-model="room.type"` will not not work. I tried binding to `v-model` as so: `:v-model="room.type"` - but that also does not work. Using `v-model="$data[room.type]"` will return the string the from the `room.type` variable and will set the `v-model` attribute dynamically, which is what we're after.

I'm not entirely clear on why using `$data` allows us to return the value rather than `$data` being interpreted as a raw string, but I'm glad this works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are using Vue 3, use `this` instead of `$data`.

For example:

```
import { reactive, createApp } from 'vue';

createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      propertyA: 'valueA',
      propertyB: 'valueB',
    });
    return state;
  };
});
```

```
<input v-for="p in ['propertyA', 'propertyB']" v-model="this[p]">
```